# Angular2 Meteor not working with Angular Material PortalModule

Tags: angular2-meteor, angular-material2

I have created an brand new Angular2 Meteor project as suggested by Angular2 Meteor tutorial (https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/bootstrapping) and installed Angular2 Material as per tutorial (https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/angular-material-and-custom-angular-auth-forms). Everything works.

Now I want to import PortalModule and so I edit **App.module.ts** adding the following lines of code:

```
import {PortalModule} from '@angular2-material/core/portal/portal-directives';
...........
@NgModule({
imports: [
    ........
    MdSidenavModule.forRoot(),
    PortalModule.forRoot()
]
)}
```

(by the way this is extacly what I do in a stadalone working Angular2 app which uses PortalModule).

Unfortunately though with Angular2 Material this generates a runtime error as startup. The top 2 lines of the stack trace on the browser console are:

[image: browser console]

I suspect this depends on some typescript configuration, so I add also my **tsconfig.json** file (which is the standard Angular2 Meteor has created while creating the project)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance